# laravel showing undefined index for menifest.js after npm run watch command

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

I am totally new to laravel. This is my first ever project in this

I followed following steps to clone laravel project to localhost from server

1. downloaded all files to local
2. Command -> composer install
3. Command -> npm install
4. Command -> php artisan key:generate
5. Command -> php artisan cache:clear

At this point project is running successfully. But when I run `npm run watch`/`num run dev` command it compiles successfully. but on the webpage it is giving me following error

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined index: /js/manifest.js (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gymnew\resources\views\index.blade.php)

\htdocs\gymnew\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php

> return new HtmlString($manifestDirectory.$manifest[$path]);
>
> "Undefined index: /js/manifest.js (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\gymnew\resources\views\index.blade.php)"

When I removed

```
{{-- Load the application scripts --}}
  @if (app()->isLocal())
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
  @else
    <script src="{{ mix('js/manifest.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ mix('js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
  @endif
```

menifest.js and vendor.js project runs fine. What is the issue with this project

This is my folder structure without npm and composer installtion

[image]

**EDIT**

It seems like `public/mix-menifest.json` not loading correct files before it was

```
{
    "/js/lang-zh-CN.9dc176ebe98d02a5c134.js": "/js/lang-zh-CN.9dc176ebe98d02a5c134.js?id=1257d3660dfcbac3686c",
    "/js/lang-zh-CN.9dc176ebe98d02a5c134.js.map": "/js/lang-zh-CN.9dc176ebe98d02a5c134.js.map?id=463cfda88e68ce67b9a3",
    "/js/lang-es.2ef093cf9e3bc265932f.js": "/js/lang-es.2ef093cf9e3bc265932f.js?id=007e30d1cdf70542875c",
    "/js/lang-es.2ef093cf9e3bc265932f.js.map": "/js/lang-es.2ef093cf9e3bc265932f.js.map?id=449a5f889009a6fe06ad",
    "/js/lang-en.1e0b5c052d0156aceaaa.js": "/js/lang-en.1e0b5c052d0156aceaaa.js?id=bd2b0ce8918b3b86a349",
    "/js/lang-en.1e0b5c052d0156aceaaa.js.map": "/js/lang-en.1e0b5c052d0156aceaaa.js.map?id=ce4c41c787fec603d079",
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js?id=fe11d3d03379933eedde",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css?id=56545756e5d3eb280eeb",
    "/js/app.js.map": "/js/app.js.map?id=b73f5b70e3615d0bde8e",
    "/css/app.css.map": "/css/app.css.map?id=8bfe67d509cd6cdcad7a",
    "/js/vendor.js": "/js/vendor.js?id=1c7691a11b5bc93a3d75",
    "/js/vendor.js.map": "/js/vendor.js.map?id=cfb3ccd1bba8e7659361",
    "/js/manifest.js": "/js/manifest.js?id=bc01cdb74e8873271d32",
    "/js/manifest.js.map": "/js/manifest.js.map?id=67b0acb205e38b325c19"
}
```

And now after`npm run dev/ npm run watch`

```
{
    "/js/lang-zh-CN.2d1b36a24dc4a427a2e1.js": "/js/lang-zh-CN.2d1b36a24dc4a427a2e1.js",
    "/js/lang-es.3281efc9e2bde13ccbfa.js": "/js/lang-es.3281efc9e2bde13ccbfa.js",
    "/js/lang-en.b1f5bde3d63ce766d15d.js": "/js/lang-en.b1f5bde3d63ce766d15d.js",
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"
}
```